# UIActivityIndicatorView nil?

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I have hooked up an activityIndicator in the storyboard and created a webView programmatically. However when I load the VC, the program crashes complaining that the activityIndicator is nil. Why is this? I confirmed that the outlet is connected properly.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com/")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        webView.load(myRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        print("loadingwebpage")

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didfinishloadingwebpage")
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the view controller?

Comment: from the storyboard. I've actually just now noticed in the documentation for the loadView() function that you can't use it if you're using the interface builder. So I guess I'll just add the webview via IB too then

Comment: If you override `loadView` then you are not actually going to have the storyboard load code execute unless you call `super.loadView`.

Comment: Yep, retire `loadView` entirely. Having that there is inconsistent with storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

You have this line :

```
view = webView
```

this mean you assign created webView to viewController's view. thats why your indicator destroy and cause crash.

add webView to viewcontroller's subview and crash will gone. change:

```
webView.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.addSubview(webView)
```